# Python: Determine whether each step in path across n arrays falls below threshold value

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, distance, dijkstra

Given n arrays of integers, is there a good algorithm with which to determine whether there is a path across those arrays such that the minimum (Euclidean) distance of each "step" along that path falls below a certain threshold value? That is, the path across all arrays will include only one member from each array, and the distance of each step of that path will be determined by the absolute distance between the values from the two arrays being compared during the given step. For instance, say you have the following arrays:

```
a = [1,3,7]
b = [10,13]
c = [13,24]
```

and

```
threshold = 3
```

In that case, you would want to determine whether any elements of a and b have a distance of 3 or less between them, and for all pairs of elements from a and b that do in fact have a distance of three or less between them, you would want to determine whether either the given member from a or the given member from b has a distance of 3 or less from any member of c. (In the example above, the only path across the integers for which the distance of each step falls below the threshold condition is 7-->10-->13.)

Here's how I'm approaching such a problem when the number of arrays is three:

```
from numpy import*

a = [1,3,7]
b = [10,13]
c = [13,24]
d = [45]

def find_path_across_three_arrays_with_threshold_value_three(a,b,c):
    '''this function takes three lists as input, and it determines whether
    there is a path across those lists for which each step of that path
    has a distance of three or less'''

    threshold = 3

    #start with a,b
    for i in a:
        for j in b:

            #if the absolute value of i-j is less than or equal to the threshold parameter (user-specified proximity value)
            if abs(i-j) <= threshold:

                for k in c:

                    if abs(i-k) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k

                    elif abs(j-k) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k

    #now start with a,c                    
    for i in a:
        for k in c:
            if abs(i-k) <= threshold:

                for j in b:

                    if abs(i-j) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k
                    elif abs(j-k) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k

    #finally, start with b,c
    for j in b:
        for k in c:
            if abs(j-k) <= threshold:

                for i in a:

                    if abs(i-j) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k
                    elif abs(i-k) <= threshold:
                        return i,j,k


if find_path_across_three_arrays_with_threshold_value_three(a,b,c):
    print "ok"
```

If you didn't know in advance, though, how many arrays there were, what would be the most efficient way of calculating whether there is a path across all n arrays, such that the distance of each "step" in the path fell below the desired threshold value? Would something like Dijkstra's algorithm be the best way to generalize this problem for n arrays?

### EDIT:

@Falko's method works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

my_list = [[1, 3, 7], [10, 13], [13, 24], [19], [16]]

def isPath(A, threshold):
        for i in range(len(A) - 1):
            #print "Finding edges from layer", i, "to", i + 1, "..."
            diffs = np.array(A[i]).reshape((-1, 1)) - np.array(A[i + 1]).reshape((1, -1))
            reached = np.any(np.abs(diffs) <= threshold, axis = 0)
            A[i + 1] = [A[i + 1][j] for j in range(len(reached)) if reached[j]]
            #print "Reachable nodes of next layer:", A[i + 1]
        return any(reached)

for i in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    new_list = []
    for j in i:
        new_list.extend([j])

    if isPath(new_list,3):
        print "threshold 3 match for ", new_list
    if isPath(new_list,10):
        print "threshold 10 match for ", new_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution (maybe related to the one from JohnB; I'm not sure):

```py
import numpy as np

def isPath(A, threshold):
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        print "Finding edges from layer", i, "to", i + 1, "..."
        diffs = np.array(A[i]).reshape((-1, 1)) - np.array(A[i + 1]).reshape((1, -1))
        reached = np.any(np.abs(diffs) <= threshold, axis = 0)
        A[i + 1] = [A[i + 1][j] for j in range(len(reached)) if reached[j]]
        print "Reachable nodes of next layer:", A[i + 1]
    return any(reached)

print isPath([[1, 3, 7], [10, 13], [13, 24]], 3)
print isPath([[1, 3, 7], [10, 13], [13, 24]], 10)
```

Output:

```
Finding edges from layer 0 to 1 ...
Reachable nodes of next layer: [10]
Finding edges from layer 1 to 2 ...
Reachable nodes of next layer: [13]
True

Finding edges from layer 0 to 1 ...
Reachable nodes of next layer: [10, 13]
Finding edges from layer 1 to 2 ...
Reachable nodes of next layer: [13]
True
```

It steps from one layer to another an checks, which nodes still can be reached given the predefined `threshold`. Unreachable nodes are removed from the array. When the loop continues, those nodes are not considered anymore.

I guess it's pretty efficient and easy to implement.

Comment: `print isPath([[1, 3, 7], [10, 13], [13, 24], [16]], 3)` returns False  but should return true: 7-->10-->13-->16. :(

Comment: Sorry, I should use ```<=``` rather than ```<```. ;)

Comment: What's the most efficient edit we can make to your code such that `print isPath([[1, 3, 7], [10, 13], [13, 24], [19], [16]], 3)` will yield True? (3-->7-->10-->13-->16*-->19*), where 16 and 19 can be reached if the last two arrays are swapped during input? Will I have to iterate through all combinations of the individual arrays exhaustively?

Comment: So what is the new rule? Two layers are allowed to be swapped or is any permutation of all layers ok?

Comment: Yes, any permutation of the layers that facilitates a path for which each step falls below the threshold value is valid. Sorry if this wasn't clear in my original post. (Now I see why my original code was wrong.)

Comment: I guess then you really need to search for connected components and find one containing nodes from all layers. At least I can't think of a simple *edit* to achieve that new behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd build up an *undirected graph*: Each number in your array is a node and nodes of neighboring rows are connected if and only if their distance is smaller than your threshold.

Then you can use a standard algorithm to determine *connected components* of the graph. You'll probably find many references and code examples about this common problem.

Finally you need to check if one component contains nodes from `a` as well as nodes from your last row, `c` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Falko: can you recommend a function I can call in Python to create such an undirected graph, and/or a function I can call on an undirected graph to see if it is connected? Any references you can offer will be appreciated.

Comment: I just corrected myself. The graph could contain two distinct connected components and still yield a path from ```a``` to ```c```. Regarding an algorithm: Currently I don't have one in my mind. But I'm still looking... ;)

Comment: Feel free to write if you find an implementation you think might be of use!

Answer (score 1):

(short answer: Floyd-Warshall is more efficient in this case than naive application of Dijkstra's)

I'm not 100% clear from your example, but it seems that you have to advance through the arrays in increasing order, and that you cannot backtrack.

ie...

```
A = [1, 300]
B = [2, 11]
C = [12, 301]
```

You go A(1) -> B(2), but there is no path to C because you can't jump to B(11) -> C(12). Similarly you can't jump A(300) -> C(301).

You could create, as you suggest, an adjacency matrix of size NM x NM where N is the |arrays| and M is |elements in each array|. You would want to use a sparse array implementation as most of the values are nil.

For each increasing pair (ai,bj), (bi,cj) you perform the pairwise calculations and store the connection if it is <= your threshold value.
The runtime for this would be N * M^2, which is smaller than the cost of finding paths (in the worst case) and so is probably acceptable. For cases where threshold << M and arrays do not contain repetitions this can be reduced to N*MlgM by sorting first. As at most threshold*M comparisons are needed for each array pair comparison.

To use Dijkstra's you'd have to run it M*M times, once for each pair of elements in arrays a and n. Which works out to O(M^2 * ElgV) (E is number of edges, V is number of vertexes) Which in the worst case E = (N-1)*M^2, and V is N*M. or N*M^4 * lg(N*M). Floyd-Warshall algorithm for all pairs of shortest paths runs in V^3, or (N*M)^3, which is smaller.

Comment: This looks great @JohnB. You don't happen to have an implementation using Floyd-Warshall within arm's reach by chance, do you? ;)

Comment: Also, to be clear, the arrays need not be traversed in increasing order. A path from C --> A --> B is fine, as is B --> A --> C, or any combination of A,B,C, just so long as the path across these three arrays includes exactly one member of each array, and the absolute difference between the two members connected by each step of the path is <= threshold value. So 1-->4-->3 is allowed, as is 4-->1-->3 , and 3-->1-->4, etc. I hope this helps clarify the necessary and sufficient conditions for a match.

Comment: There is a pseudo code implementation available in http://tinyurl.com/bigalgbook under that title. Although if the ordering doesn't matter, but you do need to hit a value from every array you'd need something different.

Off the top of my had taking Falko's python code and running on all permutations until one succeeds (N! time), or a custom Minimum spanning tree implementation. Without the ordering constraint you can end up with a fully connected graph, in which case shortest path algorithms don't guarantee hitting all vertex sets in a path.